# Android adapter dataset instantiation practices with Realm

Tags: android, realm

I was wondering does it matter where you instantiate adapters dataset with Realm? I like to fetch all the data that any adapter needs in the adapters constructor and thus instantiate the dataset there, but almost all examples I've seen fetch the data beforehand in the activity creating the adapter and then pass it to the adapter as a parameter.

With SQLite this seems even more arbitrary, but since I'm using Realm I need to open a realm connection every time I want to access the database and to keep the data available I need to keep the connection open. Keeping this connection open in the activity seems unnecessary since you might need to make queries in the adapter thus having to open a connection to realm within the adapter anyways.

Is there some higher reason to fetch the dataset beforehand or is this just a matter of preference?

Comment: It is just a matter of preference, but IMO mixing fetching data with displaying them seems to couple them more highly than I would prefer in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

> since I'm using Realm I need to open a realm connection every time I want to access the database

Wrong, you just need 1 open instance for that given thread in order to access the database.

> Keeping this connection open in the activity "seems unnecessary" since you might need to make queries in the adapter

In which case you can have the activity-level Realm instance as a "scoped dependency", that you can share through the Context via `getSystemService()` if that's what you like to do.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Realm realm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(realm != null) {
           realm.close();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    ...

    @Override
    public Object getSystemService(String key) {
        if("REALM".equals(key)) {
            return realm;
        }
        return super.getSystemService(key);
    }
}

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyModelViewHolder> {
    private final Context context;
    Realm realm;

    RealmResults<MyModel> results;
    private final RealmChangeListener listener = new RealmChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(Object element) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        //noinspection ResourceType
        realm = (Realm)context.getSystemService("REALM");
        results = realm.where(MyModel.class).findAll();
        results.addChangeListener(listener);
    }

    ...
}
```

> thus having to open a connection to realm within the adapter anyways.

wrong

> Is there some higher reason to fetch the dataset beforehand or is this just a matter of preference?

It's because your Adapter, which is just supposed to describe how to show the elements of a dataset, become a God that also determines the data that it must show.

Although to be fair, it's actually harder to externally manage the data-set; something *must* hold a strong reference to the result set anyways. So when I don't really bother with unit-testability, I do obtain the results inside the Adapter itself. It does work.